# Button Click doesn't fire when using ripple-js in Angular

Tags: angular, ripplejs

I am using `ripple-js` library from [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ripple-js) in my Angular 5 project. As soon as I add the `ripple` class to my buttons, the ripple effect starts working, however the button click stops firing.

Here's a sample HTML of my button -

```
<div id="btnSearch" class="search_button_right tooltipstr ripple" title="Click here to Search">
                    <button class="btn" type="submit" (click)="Search();">
                        Search
                    </button>
                </div>
```

Please advise what could be the issue.

Comment: Did you try adding the ripple class to the button instead of the div ?

Comment: yes @CornelC, tried the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the CSS z-index property of a button and its parent class. If Z-index value of a button lesser than the div's z-index value. It won't work.
Try giving high value in button.

Comment: There is no z-index value assigned to any of them

Comment: then try adding it.

Comment: @Nitesh I tried adding an event in the parent class of that button. It's working.